# API to change the credit card used by a google wallet subscription?

Tags: android-pay

Again I am frustrated by the lack of documentation involved in developing using Google Wallet as a payment gateway and I may switch to another service.

My new question is as follows:

Can I programmatically change the payment card utilized by a Google Wallet for digital goods subscription?

If a card utilized in a subscription expires, that is on the user, However, If I do not provide a means of changing the payment card elegantly, that is on me!

Does anyone know how this can be done? Or would I have to create a whole new subscription to produce this effect? This should be a basic feature of any payment gateway so I am assuming that I am missing something.

It should also be noted that creating a new subscription may be problematic without an ability to cancel the previous subscription via the API. Provided that both the old and new cards are still valid, it would attempt to process the payments for both subscriptions!

On a side note, why does it seem that the Google Wallet API is missing so many key features? (annual subscriptions, subscription cancellation, the issue mentioned above, etc...?)

Thanks again everyone!

Answer (score 1):

If Google can't successfully charge, they'll send you a [failure postback](https://developers.google.com/wallet/digital/docs/subscriptions#6) which you can use to evaluate what to do with the subscription.

---

It would be best if you don't equate Wallet to a "payment gateway" (or credit card processing service/gateway) because it isn't.

At the end of the day, Wallet basically gives you some "access" to a Wallet User's data. It's up to the Wallet users' to add/remove whatever payment instruments they have in their Google Wallet.

- in Wallet for Digital, Google also handles the transaction - the processing part, so you're freed of any PCI compliance, and related payment infrastructure to get stuff going.
- Instant Buy, Google will send you a "virtual card" for you to process the transaction using your own/existing credit card processor/gateway. In this case, you do have to be PCI compliant and have existing infrastructure.

In both cases, you don't have access to the actual Wallet users' payment data. Google locks that stuff down.

Hth....